# Weird side effect of "SET STATISTICS TIME ON" in SQL Server 2008R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;

DECLARE @String AS VARCHAR(10), @I INT = 1    

WHILE @I <= 3
BEGIN
SET @String = CASE @I WHEN 1 THEN 'First' WHEN 2 THEN 'Second' WHEN 3 THEN 'Third' END;

    SELECT  @String AS [StatsTimeOff] OPTION(RECOMPILE)

    SET STATISTICS TIME ON

    SELECT @String AS [StatsTimeOn]  OPTION(RECOMPILE)

    SET STATISTICS TIME OFF

SET @I +=1;
END
```

Returns

```
StatsTimeOff
------------
First

StatsTimeOn
-----------
First


StatsTimeOff
------------
Second

StatsTimeOn
-----------
First


StatsTimeOff
------------
Third

StatsTimeOn
-----------
First
```

Why does the combination of `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` and  `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` apparently make the variable regress to its initial value?

I've never seen `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` having an influence on the result before.

Am I missing something, here?

Comment: How is it related? When @pDateFrom is '2013-01-01' and SET STATISTICS TIME ON is there, it results in a set of NULL instead of a set of '2013-01-01'.

Comment: I just checked if adding an ORDER By clause changed anything, but it doesn't.

Comment: @MartinSmith Here you are

Comment: I can reproduce this on SQL Server 2008. Not in SQL Server 2012. Also if you remove `option (recompile)` it works as it should.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - Same here. Repro 2008 not 2012

Comment: @MartinSmith If you add a value for `DateFrom` on the first row in `@TBL` that value will be reused for all consecutive iterations.

Comment: Very strange. @Serge I'd report it on Connect. Maybe this is a fixed bug in 2012 that they didn't bother back porting to previous versions but at least they'll hopefully give an explanation.

Comment: @Serge - I took the liberty of simplifying the example to the minimal possible that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @MartinSmith it's for the best then

Comment: @MartinSmith It does not have to be a cursor and no table involved. http://pastebin.com/SjEYGBAH

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - Just tested that one as well!

Comment: Does not happen in SQL Server 2005. So a regression in SQL Server 2008 then.

Comment: I can reproduce in sql 2008 RTM but can not reproduce in 2008 R2 RTM

Comment: Also happens in 2008 SP3 (10.0.5846). Just as an aside, and with the disclaimer that I work for SQL Sentry, but if you are just trying to time your queries, execute them by generating an actual plan from [Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer). In addition to more intuitive plans, you get duration, reads etc. for every statement, without having to ever fiddle with any `SET` commands yourself. That said, Plan Explorer also reflects that SQL Server does still mess this up if you *do* use a batch that contains those commands.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - Well the behaviour of `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` did change quite radically between the versions then they noticed that bug and it got reverted back for a while. Maybe it is kind of related [to that original issue](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html#SPandCUs)

Comment: @MartinSmith Looks related. According to [this](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options), assigning the value to a variable will not use "parameter embedding optimization". The parameter is instead added as a parameter in the query plan and works just fine. So something to do with "parameter embedding optimization". BTW it also works fine if the query is not the first statement directly after `set statistics time on`. Add `if 1 = 0 print 1` in between and it works fine. (Or just `if 1 = 1`)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - Good spot. The original version of this question had `SET STATISTICS IO ON;SET STATISTICS TIME ON;` so I suppose an easy workaround would be to just reverse the order of those. I agree, looks like the literal parameter value is embedded in the plan then somehow that gets recycled rather than recompiled for the subsequent executions. Trace Flags `8605`, `8606` only show output for the first invocation.

Comment: what edition and exact version is this happening with? Trying this with SQL Server Developer Edition, Version 10.50.1600.1 but it is not exhibiting the behavior you describe - query seems to work as it should.

Comment: I obtain this behaviour on 1.50.4000

Answer (score 1):

This does appear to be a bug, and one that I can reproduce in SQL 2008 R2 SP2.  I believe your case statement takes a way from it a bit, as you can reproduce the issue by simply selecting @I, where I would rewrite it as follows:

```
DECLARE @I INT = 1   

WHILE @I <= 3
BEGIN
    SELECT FirstRun = @I OPTION(RECOMPILE)

    SET STATISTICS TIME ON

    SELECT SecondRun = @I OPTION(RECOMPILE) 

    SELECT ThirdRun = @I OPTION(RECOMPILE)

    SET @I +=1
END
```

Since I believe this is a bug, I'm not going to attempt to fix it.  However, I would suggest moving all SSMS settings to the beginning of your batch and run it all that way.  This work-around would have avoided the issue.

My speculation is that when the option is changed it goes back through the entire query to try to figure out how to make the execution plan, and when it does that it's grabbing (incorrectly) the initial value of the variable.  Since it's using OPTION(RECOMPILE) that parameter is placed into the plan as a constant, which is why you only see this bug when using that option.

It is very odd that if you run that select statement again immediately after that it starts to return the proper value.  This is something I did not expect, and gives you another work-around allowing you to turn your statistics on and run something else after it, such as, oddly enough, SET STATISTICS IO ON.